# Extra space created around object when using the shaper tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

When I try to use shaper tool to merge two paths, it creates all that extra space up top.

https://vimeo.com/305816637

Answer (score 2):

That is the Shaper tool (not the Shape Builder)

---

Just select the *Shape Builder Tool* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) and simply drag to join them.

[image]

If you want to use the *Shaper Tool* (as it is less destructive and more forgiving on mistakes later on) you can draw a little squiggly line across the areas you don't want (using the *Shaper Tool*) and they will "get erased".

---

Read more about these tools at [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/building-new-shapes-using-shape.html)